# Process monitoring: determining number of expected bad widgets in your sample. model set up

Tags: inference, latent-variable, pymc

Set up: We are testing widgets. If a widget passed testing it moves out of the factory. If it failed we will test it up to 3 times. There are some number of widgets that will never pass even if we tried forever. How can we construct a model to infer the number of samples that will never pass no matter how many time we attempt to test the widgets.

I was thinking about using pymc3. This is the model I set up [from](https://am207.github.io/2017/wiki/Lab7_bioassay.html#a-few-words-about-pymc3):

```
from theano import shared

step = blood_data[:,0].astype(int)

# Let's make this a theano shared variable so that we can make predictions for new values later
step_shared = shared(step)

# Sample size in each group
n = np.sum(blood_data[:,1:], axis=1, dtype=int)

# The sample size has to be a shared variable too
n_shared = shared(n)

# Outcomes
failures = blood_data[:,1].astype(int)

print(n, failures, step)
(array([53349,  9085,  1473]), array([3333, 2295,  650]), array([1, 2, 3]))

from pymc3 import Normal, Binomial, sample, Model # Import relevant distributions
from pymc3.math import invlogit

with Model() as bioassay_model:

    # Logit-linear model parameters
    alpha = Normal('alpha', 0, sd=100)
    beta = Normal('beta', 0, sd=100)

    # Calculate probabilities of death
    theta = invlogit(alpha + beta * step_shared)

    # Data likelihood
    obs_failures = Binomial('obs_failures', n=n_shared, p=theta, observed=failures)
```

But this predicts the number of failures as a function of steps. How can I try to model this latent variable that I believe to be there?  Any help would be much appreciated.